# How i convert tcl list to java list in tcl file

Tags: java, list, tcl

I am able to convert java list to tcl list but unable to convert  **Tcl list to java list**.

**sample.tcl:-**

```tcl
global mgr;
set mgr [java::new sample_impl]

proc sample {arg_list} {
    # what i need to do inside hear

    $::mgr sample_impl_in_java "java_list";  ## hear i call the java function that takes the java_list as a argument 
}

set var "hello"

sample {$var "world"}; ## pass a tcl list in sample function in tcl
```

**sample_impl.java:-**

```java
 public void sample_impl_in_java(List listObj) {
     System.out.println(listObj);
 }
```

Anyone can please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Java lists and Tcl lists have fairly different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's list type is rather like a Java ArrayList, but the API is different and the modification semantics are different. Converting one to the other requires a manual step:

```tcl
proc sample {arg_list} {
    # Make an ArrayList
    set jlist [java::new java.util.ArrayList]

    # Copy the items over as strings; if you want a list of other things, this is the bit you change
    foreach item $arg_list {
        $jlist add [java::new String $item]
    }

    # Do the call
    $::mgr sample_impl_in_java $jlist
}
```

You probably want to call this something like:

```
set var "hello"
sample [list $var "world"]
```

The other way will work, but the result is unlikely to be what you expect.